# Get the Multiple images & its positions from Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, for-loop, foreach

I am fetching **image** & its **positions** [**left**(x) & **top** (y)]   from json with help of below code & displaying in html page.... if there is single image in [json](https://pastebin.com/KWPwA9TN), than its working fine....

```
var mask1;

$(document).ready(function() 
{

    var maskedImageUrla = "";
    var coordinates = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };

    var width = 0;
    var height = 0;

    $.getJSON('2images.json', function(json) 
    {
        for (let layer of json.layers) 
        {
            width = layer.width;
            height = layer.height;
            if (layer.layers && layer.layers.length > 0)
            {
                for (let temp of layer.layers) 
                {

                    if (temp.src) maskedImageUrla = temp.src;
                    else if (temp.layers) 
                    {
                        for (let tl of temp.layers)
                            if (tl.src) 
                            {
                               maskedImageUrla = 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + tl.src;
                                coordinates.x = temp.x;
                                coordinates.y = temp.y;
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

        var mask1 = $(".container").mask({
            maskImageUrl: maskedImageUrla, // get image
            onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

                img.css({
                    "position": "fixed",
                    "left": coordinates.x + "px", // get x
                    "top": coordinates.y + "px"   // get y
                });
            }
        });

        fileupa1.onchange = function() {
            mask1.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileupa1.files[0]));
        };
    });

}); // end of document ready
```

**Requirement** :

but if there are multiple images in json, than **only one image** is fetching, but how to fetch all images [src] & its positions [ x & y ]....

Codepen [ 2 images json ] : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/RdwXpZ

**Edit** : Below is Code snippet :

```js
var mask1;

$(document).ready(function() 
{

    var maskedImageUrla = "";
    var coordinates = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };

    var width = 0;
    var height = 0;

 var json = {
  "name": "newyear collage",
  "layers": [
    {
      "x": 0,
      "height": 612,
      "layers": [
        {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0
        },
        {
          "x": 160,
          "layers": [
            {
              "x": 0,
              "src": "AX7HBOE.png",
              "y": 0,
              "name": "mask_image_1"
            },
            {
              "name": "useradd_ellipse1"
            }
          ],
          "y": 291,
          "name": "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x": 25,
          "layers": [
            {
              "x": 0,
              "src": "o5P9tdZ.png",
              "y": 0,
              "name": "mask_image_2"
            },
            {
              "name": "useradd_ellipse_2"
            }
          ],
          "y": 22,
          "name": "user_image_2"
        }
      ],
      "y": 0,
      "width": 612,
      "name": "newyearcollage08"
    }
  ]
};
 
    
        for (let layer of json.layers) 
  {
            width = layer.width;
            height = layer.height;
            if (layer.layers && layer.layers.length > 0)
   {
                for (let temp of layer.layers) 
    {

                    if (temp.src) maskedImageUrla = temp.src;
                    else if (temp.layers) 
     {
                        for (let tl of temp.layers)
                            if (tl.src) 
       {
                               maskedImageUrla = 'https://i.imgur.com/' + tl.src;
                                coordinates.x = temp.x;
                                coordinates.y = temp.y;
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

        var mask1 = $(".container").mask({
            maskImageUrl: maskedImageUrla, // get image
            onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

                img.css({
                    "position": "fixed",
                    "left": coordinates.x + "px", // get x
                    "top": coordinates.y + "px"   // get y
                });
            }
        });

        fileupa1.onchange = function() {
            mask1.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileupa1.files[0]));
        };
  

}); // end of document ready

// jq plugin for mask
(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
            container.selected(evt);
            prevX = evt.clientX;
            prevY = evt.clientY;
        };

        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {
            if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                    return; // position has not changed
                settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                container.updateStyle();
            }
        };

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
           image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                };

                img = new Image();
                img.src = settings.imageUrl;
                 img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                img.onload = function() {
                    settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                    settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                    context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                    initImage = false;
                };
            }, 0);
        };

        // change the draggable image
        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            if (img)
                img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle();
        };

        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            if (div)
                div.remove();
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp
{
border: 1px solid #DDDDDD; 
display: flex;
background :silver;
}

.container canvas {
 display: block;
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 50px;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<head>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
image 1 
<input id="fileupa1"  type="file" >

<div class="container">
</div>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let jsonData2 = {
  "path" : " newyear collage\/",
  "info" : {
    "author" : "",
    "keywords" : "",
    "file" : "newyear collage",
    "date" : "sRGB",
    "title" : "",
    "description" : "Normal",
    "generator" : "Export Kit v1.2.8"
  },
  "name" : "newyear collage",
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 612,
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 0,
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "height" : 612,
          "y" : 0,
          "width" : 612,
          "shapeType" : "rectangle",
          "type" : "shape",
          "name" : "bg_rectangle"
        },
        {
          "x" : 160,
          "height" : 296,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 296,
              "src" : "6b8e734c46539dbc73f51e8f65d29fe3_frame0.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 429,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_1"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 188,
              "y" : 122,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse1"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 291,
          "width" : 429,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 25,
          "height" : 324,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 324,
              "src" : "eb8e531ec340da14688a6343769286c0_frame1.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 471,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_2"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 209,
              "y" : 136,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse_2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 22,
          "width" : 471,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_2"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0,
      "width" : 612,
      "type" : "group",
      "name" : "newyearcollage08"
    }
  ]
};
let jsonData = {
  "path": " UNEVENSHAPES\/",
  "info": {
    "author": "",
    "keywords": "",
    "file": "UNEVENSHAPES",
    "date": "Uncalibrated",
    "title": "",
    "description": "Normal",
    "generator": "Export Kit v1.2.8"
  },
  "name": "UNEVENSHAPES",
  "layers": [{
    "x": 0,
    "height": 612,
    "layers": [{
        "x": 0,
        "color": "0xFFFFFF",
        "height": 612,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 612,
        "shapeType": "rectangle",
        "type": "shape",
        "name": "rectangle1"
      },
      {
        "x": 20,
        "height": 377,
        "layers": [{
            "x": 0,
            "height": 377,
            "src": "d15ad70281961be451263b418a07798b_frame0.png",
            "y": 0,
            "width": 218,
            "type": "image",
            "name": "mask_pic1"
          },
          {
            "radius": "27 \/ 27",
            "color": "0xACACAC",
            "x": 52,
            "y": 257,
            "height": 53,
            "width": 53,
            "shapeType": "ellipse",
            "type": "shape",
            "name": "useradd_ellipse1"
          }
        ],
        "y": 215,
        "width": 218,
        "type": "group",
        "name": "user_pic1"
      },
      {
        "x": 191,
        "height": 120,
        "layers": [{
            "x": 0,
            "height": 120,
            "src": "2b5d28d0439bc3ce1d856e6c4e5607be_frame1.png",
            "y": 0,
            "width": 268,
            "type": "image",
            "name": "mask_pic2"
          },
          {
            "radius": "26 \/ 27",
            "color": "0xACACAC",
            "x": 115,
            "y": 43,
            "height": 53,
            "width": 53,
            "shapeType": "ellipse",
            "type": "shape",
            "name": "useradd_ellipse2"
          }
        ],
        "y": 472,
        "width": 268,
        "type": "group",
        "name": "user_pic2"
      },
      {
        "x": 414,
        "height": 302,
        "layers": [{
            "x": 0,
            "height": 302,
            "src": "52c93b6e0a0ffeeb670d0981f89f7fa5_frame2.png",
            "y": 0,
            "width": 178,
            "type": "image",
            "name": "mask_pic3"
          },
          {
            "radius": "26 \/ 27",
            "color": "0xACACAC",
            "x": 69,
            "y": 182,
            "height": 53,
            "width": 53,
            "shapeType": "ellipse",
            "type": "shape",
            "name": "useradd_ellipse3"
          }
        ],
        "y": 290,
        "width": 178,
        "type": "group",
        "name": "user_pic3"
      },
      {
        "x": 374,
        "height": 377,
        "layers": [{
            "x": 0,
            "height": 377,
            "src": "e92f354018aa8f7e6d279601a868a6b2_frame3.png",
            "y": 0,
            "width": 218,
            "type": "image",
            "name": "mask_pic4"
          },
          {
            "radius": "26 \/ 27",
            "color": "0xACACAC",
            "x": 129,
            "y": 60,
            "height": 53,
            "width": 53,
            "shapeType": "ellipse",
            "type": "shape",
            "name": "useradd_ellipse4"
          }
        ],
        "y": 20,
        "width": 218,
        "type": "group",
        "name": "user_pic4"
      },
      {
        "x": 150,
        "height": 120,
        "layers": [{
            "x": 0,
            "height": 120,
            "src": "010054750abb290d1bd7fcecfab60524_frame4.png",
            "y": 0,
            "width": 269,
            "type": "image",
            "name": "mask_pic5"
          },
          {
            "radius": "27 \/ 27",
            "color": "0xACACAC",
            "x": 103,
            "y": 15,
            "height": 53,
            "width": 53,
            "shapeType": "ellipse",
            "type": "shape",
            "name": "useradd_ellipse5"
          }
        ],
        "y": 20,
        "width": 269,
        "type": "group",
        "name": "user_pic5"
      },
      {
        "x": 20,
        "height": 302,
        "layers": [{
            "x": 0,
            "height": 302,
            "src": "e7a5874b58376883adbeafea7ce5e572_frame5.png",
            "y": 0,
            "width": 176,
            "type": "image",
            "name": "mask_pic6"
          },
          {
            "radius": "26 \/ 27",
            "color": "0xACACAC",
            "x": 50,
            "y": 68,
            "height": 53,
            "width": 53,
            "shapeType": "ellipse",
            "type": "shape",
            "name": "useradd_ellipse6"
          }
        ],
        "y": 20,
        "width": 176,
        "type": "group",
        "name": "user_pic6"
      },
      {
        "x": 222,
        "height": 335,
        "layers": [{
            "x": 0,
            "height": 335,
            "src": "591743efa89d8ee936a6d660d52e82b2_frame6.png",
            "y": 0,
            "width": 265,
            "type": "image",
            "name": "mask_pic7"
          },
          {
            "radius": "26 \/ 27",
            "color": "0xACACAC",
            "x": 126,
            "y": 114,
            "height": 53,
            "width": 53,
            "shapeType": "ellipse",
            "type": "shape",
            "name": "useradd_ellipse7"
          }
        ],
        "y": 123,
        "width": 265,
        "type": "group",
        "name": "user_pic7"
      },
      {
        "x": 123,
        "height": 334,
        "layers": [{
            "x": 0,
            "height": 334,
            "src": "22997a60cf61d7b59e92620b86ab86d6_frame7.png",
            "y": 0,
            "width": 264,
            "type": "image",
            "name": "mask_pic8"
          },
          {
            "radius": "27 \/ 27",
            "color": "0xACACAC",
            "x": 73,
            "y": 167,
            "height": 53,
            "width": 53,
            "shapeType": "ellipse",
            "type": "shape",
            "name": "useradd_ellipse8"
          }
        ],
        "y": 155,
        "width": 264,
        "type": "group",
        "name": "user_pic8"
      }
    ],
    "y": 0,
    "width": 612,
    "type": "group",
    "name": "unevenshape04"
  }]
};

function getData(data) {
var dataObj = {};
let layer1 = data.layers;
let layer2 = layer1[0].layers;
console.log('New Data');
  for (i = 1; i < layer2.length; i++) {
    var x = layer2[i].x;
    var y = layer2[i].y;
    var src = layer2[i].layers[0].src;
    
    console.log(x,y,src);
  }
  
}
getData(jsonData);
getData(jsonData2);
```

Comment: Thanks, i applied your code here : https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/KEdZaZ  , it worked fine, can you please help me to get relative x & y instead of x & y , means `src x = outermost x + next outermost x + 2nd next outermost x... so on`

Answer (score 0):

the json part is ok. But after that in

```
var mask1 = $(".container").mask({
    maskImageUrl: maskedImageUrla, // get image
```

you create only one image, with the last value of maskedImageUrla.

What you can do is store your images in an array and iterate over them, as in :

```
$.getJSON('2images.json', function(json) 
    {
        const images = [];

        for (let layer of json.layers) 
        ...
        for (let tl of temp.layers)
            if (tl.src) {
                images.push({
                    maskedImageUrla = 'http://piccellsapp.com:1337/parse/files/PfAppId/' + tl.src,
                    coordinates.x = temp.x,
                    coordinates.y = temp.y
                })                
             }
             ...
             images.forEach(image => {
                 var mask1 = $(".container").mask({
                     maskImageUrl: image.maskedImageUrla, // get image
                     onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {
                         img.css({
                             "position": "fixed",
                             "left": image.coordinates.x + "px", // get x
                             "top": image.coordinates.y + "px"   // get y
                          });
                      }
                  });

                 fileupa1.onchange = function() {
                     mask1.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileupa1.files[0]));
                 };
             });
```

Comment: i updated your code , please check link : https://pastebin.com/RxUbXLie , but no images are displaying, what wrong i done ?

Comment: you forgot to wrap maskedImageUrla and coordinates in an image object, and then use it as image.maskedImageUrla, etc : https://pastebin.com/RTedEQyz